# Fetch RTF from Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a Word document and would like to export the content including the format as RTF (or html).

```
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("file.docx");
        currentDoc.SaveAs("file.rtf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
        currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("file.rtf");
        Word.Range range = currentDoc.Range();
        String RTFText = range.Text;
```

I've tried the code above, but i seem to get just the Text, without hte format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the rtf code just try to use:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("file.docx");
currentDoc.SaveAs("file.rtf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
```

And then open it like a normal text file:

```
string rtf = File.ReadAllText("file.rtf");
```

Using your method doesn't work because you're accessing *Text* property, so Word gives you only plain text.

Comment: I was thinking way to complex. Thanks!