# Invoking Word for rtf to docx conversion

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, rtf, office-interop

I have a need to routinely programmatically convert *.rtf files into *.docx. Manually, this works just fine with Save As inside Word 2007 ... the resulting docx behaves just fine.  Programmatically, I can't get it to work.

What I tried is basically the following:

[Fetch RTF from Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647018/fetch-rtf-from-word/4647132#4647132)

... but in the reverse direction. Instead of opening *.docx and using SaveAs to *.rtf, I'm opening the *.rtf and using SaveAs to *.docx.  However, the resulting file won't open, and so evidently there's something I don't understand.  Is

```
wordApp.Documents.Open(@"D:\Bar\foo.rtf")
```

not a legit thing to do?

Any thoughts about how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: The program itself runs without errors.  If I try opening the resulting file, it merely yields 'Word experienced an error trying to open the file'.  When I try to look at it with Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool, it reports 'File contains corrupted data'.

Comment: can u please upload an example of the rtf which gives error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code, it works for me

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\TestDocument.rtf");
currentDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\TestDocument.doc", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97);
```

I got the same error when I tried to use wdFormatDocument or wdFormatDocumentDefault

EDIT: this is an update to the code, it converts it but u will get the error once then it never appeared again!!

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\TestDocument.rtf");
currentDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\TestDocument", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
currentDoc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Does MS Word have to be installed on the client machine for this to work ?

Comment: If you run this code from an asp.net then it should be installed on the web server, if you run this code from a windows app then your (client) machine should have MS Word installed

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the code where you are calling `SaveAs`? I am curious which `Word.WdSaveFormat` you are specifying. It sounds like it is saving the rtf data, but changing the extension to .docx.

Comment: I'm using WdFormatDocument ... but good idea, I'll play with some others

Comment: Ah, when I use WdFormatDocumentDefault I can get to docx successfully, and also WdFormatDocument97 gets successfully to doc... thanks for the idea.  Maybe the semantics of wdFormatDocument are different than I expected.

Comment: I marked Pr0fesso0rX as the answer since that complete example is most likely useful to more folks in future ... but thanks, Mark, your hint got me there

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that does conversion. The code is almost the same as shown above, with some small (but important) difference - it is necessary to use references (not objects themselves):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _Doc =  _App.Documents.Open("c:/xxx.rtf");

object _DocxFileName = "C:/xxx.docx";
Object FileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;

_Doc.SaveAs2(ref _DocxFileName, ref FileFormat);
```