# Editable Word Document Report in DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I am generating my Report using DevExpress third party tool. my requirement is i have to print report in editable word document that end user can edit text and print.

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress has a sample on how to export to doc/docx: http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4530

Needs DevExpress version 2012.2.6 to work though. If you don't have that version I think you need to check for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XtraReport.ExportToRtf()`. See [here for the documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_ExportToRtftopic185)

Microsoft Word will open and save an *.rtf* document without any problems. If you really need the output in *.doc* or *.docx* format, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903742/1077279).

Comment: just adding to this, you can stream the RTF output into [Rich Edit Document Server](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#DocumentServer/CustomDocument15092) and from there to e.g. .docx