# How to save RTF content as a DOCX

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some rtf content which is stored in the database as varchar. They originated from RichTextBoxes.

I want to concatenate the rtf content and save them as a Word document. How can I do this?

I found that the RichTextBox class has a SaveFile method which I can use to save a DOCX:

```
objRichTextBox.SaveFile("Temp.docx", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

However a problem occurs when I try to add RTF content to the RichTextBox:

```
            RichTextBox objRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();           
            objRichTextBox.Rtf = objRichTextBox.Rtf + "Hello";
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: File format is not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903304/invoking-word-for-rtf-to-docx-conversion

Comment: No, it's completely different. I neither have a saved RTF file somewhere nor do I have a RichTextBox on a form. When I just declare one and try to use it, it gives the error above.

Comment: You can't change `Rtf` property of  `RichTextBox` in this manner since it contains data in `rtf` format, and appending "Hello" to it  breaks format integrity.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Andy. I now understand the error. But how can I save the RTF content as a .docx? I can't open an existing RTF document, as I don't have a saved RTF file.

Comment: Okay, I found an actual question that is similar, now that I understand the problem, thanks to @[Andy Korneyev].

Answer (score 0):

Check [this open-source OpenXMLWriter tool](http://www.openxml.biz/OpenXMLWriter.html) that shows how to generate DocX based on the content of Richtext control.

Or you may [invoke MS Word to convert RTF file to DocX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903304/invoking-word-for-rtf-to-docx-conversion).