# WPF Richtextbox open RTF file as plain text

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, openfiledialog

I am trying to open a file to view the contents as plain text inside a `RichTextbox` on a `Button` click. Nothing seems to work properly.

```
private void loadFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile1.FileName = "Document"; 
    openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.*";
    openFile1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Rich Text Format|*.rtf|Word Document|*.docx|Word 97-2003 Document|*.doc";

    if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && openFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        //richTextbox1.Document.ContentStart = File.ReadAllText(openFile1.FileName);
    }
}
```

I am using WPF and the LoadFile method doesn't work. I'd like to be able to select a file from the `OpenFileDialog` and have it be loaded as plain text inside the `RichTextbox`. Without seeing added code from file formats.

The behavior I'd like is similar to opening an .rtf, selecting all text, and pasting that result into the `RichTextbox`. How can I do that with a button click?

Comment: I would have thought that you would need to open the file in Word, select all text and set the RTB text to the content. If you were to open a .doc or .rtf file in Notepad say, you would see the all the header characters which you don't seem to want ("Without seeing added code from file formats"

Comment: Any way of doing this without opening the file?

Comment: Mind that you cannot simply load a `.doc` or a `.docx` file into a `RichTextBox`. These types do not contain RTF-formatted text, so will have to save them as RTF-files first...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TextRange` and `FileStream`

```
if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
{             
  TextRange range;
  System.IO.FileStream fStream;

  if (System.IO.File.Exists(openFile1.FileName))
  {
      range = new TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
      fStream = new System.IO.FileStream(openFile1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
      range.Load(fStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf );

      fStream.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `System.Windows.DataFormats.Text` to `System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf`

Comment: This will open the file and read as RTF. However it will not paste plain text and will not work with other formats such as .doc and .docx

Comment: I have edited the title to open RTF files as plain text since .docx files can't be opened in a richtextbox. This is the best answer for that.

Comment: This answer should convert to plain text. Use `range.ClearAllProperties()` to do so.

Comment: Great WPF solution for converting RTF files to plain text.  Use range.Text for the plain text output.  It took about 10 Google attempts to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `richTextbox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(openFile1.FileName))`?

Comment: it's more slow but you can try this one: `richTextBox.Selection.Load(stream,DataFormats.Rtf);`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @AbZy, you need to clear the formatting first:

```
    private void loadFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile1.FileName = "Document";
        openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.*";
        openFile1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Rich Text Format|*.rtf|Word Document|*.docx|Word 97-2003 Document|*.doc";

        if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var range = new TextRange(rtf.Document.ContentStart, rtf.Document.ContentEnd);

            using (var fStream = new FileStream(openFile1.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                // load as RTF, text is formatted
                range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                fStream.Close();
            }
            // clear the formatting, turning into plain text
            range.ClearAllProperties();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great for RTF documents and strips formatting. How can this be applied to Word Doc format?

Comment: Short answer is that you will have to convert .doc or .docx to RTF first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647018/fetch-rtf-from-word/4647132 . A `RichTextbox` supports RTF, and Word .doc and .docx have more features than RTF