# Change from .rtf to .docx in C# for visual studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, richtextbox

I've been tasked to try and alter a visual studios windows app that a former coworker had made. I have only used a very little C# code and am pretty new to Visual Studios. Below is the code I'm working with and need to change the .rtf to .doc format. We need to have a .doc so we can have a header and other word formats that are not supported by rich text. Thanks for any help!! Not really sure it can be done based on my searches and forums I've been reading.

```
  try
        {
            if (action == 0)
            {
                richTextBoxLetter.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\diewes\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Letters\Letter1_Template.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); //Lan location

            }
            else if (action == 1)
            {
                richTextBoxLetter.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\diewes\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Letters\Letter2_Template.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the document and convert it  Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647018/fetch-rtf-from-word/4647132#4647132)

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\diewes\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Letters\Letter2_Template.rtf");
currentDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\TestDocument.doc",  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
currentDoc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```